# For apache-tomcat using logger framework vs redirecting STDOUT to catalina.out

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, logging

In apache-tomcat are there any **performance benefits** of using some logging framework like log4j or java.util.logging over printing to stdout which gets dumped to catalina.out (which is the default behavior)?

Functionally both are same for my use-case since I don't need any extra formatting for logged messages.

I would like to know the benefits of using a logging framework here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically, depending on your output, you might see a small (microscopic) performance penalty moving to log4j since it will lock the output file for the time it takes to write an entire message (so that messages won't get mixed together when multiple threads write at the same time) versus the standard PrintWriter.  However, the PrintWriter does do some locking so it is uncertain how much the difference will be.  Also, if you do have multiple threads printing then log4j will give you much more usable output.  If you don't care about that then, for performance, just don't log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see performance benefits, from that perspective just go with whatever provides your functionality.

Adding something like log4j is so easy anyway though, and provides so much more future flexibility, that I'd never even think of relying on stdout for a webapp output, no matter how limited my current requirement.

Edit: it's not just formatting of messages, stuff like including class-that-wrote-the-log-entry, line of code, thread name, etc - all of these can be included in logs "free" once you're using a logging framework, and they're just not available with stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the info! With all the extra formatting won't it affect the response time for the webapp?

Comment: FYI, for my use-case, I am concerned at sub-millisecond level response times.

Comment: I would advise benchmarking it, see if a fully featured logging option does materially affect your response times.  I've seen log4j write plenty distinct messages before the millisecond counters "tick over", so you might notice zero degradation, but I certainly can't guarantee that will be your own outcome for such a time-sensitive app.

Answer (score 0):

besides formatting there are many advantages to using logger instead print to console. And perfomance too. For example you can simple switch before log levels to achive better perfomance. You can achive additional perfomance when use right logger like logback.
For example logback has feature use placeholders in log message

```
log.debug ("Result of big function = {}", bigAndLongMethod())
```

this will be faster then

```
log.debug("Result of big function = " + bigAndLongMethod())
```

because in first case `bigAndLongMethod()` willn't be executed if your loglevel higher then debug.

Using some additional appenders can increase perfomance to, i.e. redirect log to other host or log into db.

As additional benefit you will get more standart-comliant log support in you project, and you be more sotisfacted with it in future, even you don't see any difference right now.